# Which functions have the same arc length to the origin at every point as the *signed* curvature at the point?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Which functions $y\left( x \right)$ have the same arc length $s$ to the origin at every point as the *signed* curvature $\kappa$ at the point?

We know the formulas for the [arc length $s$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integration)
$$
s\left( a, b, \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right) = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \operatorname{d}x
$$
and [*signed* curvature $\kappa$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Graph_of_a_function)
$$
\kappa\left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}, \frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}} \right) = \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}}}{\left( 1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \text{.}\\
$$

Since we are talking about the length of the function $y\left( x \right)$ from the origin to every point, here $a = 0$ and $b = x$, giving us a nonlinear, higher-order ordinal differential equation:
$$
\begin{align*}
s\left( 0, x, \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right) &= \kappa\left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}, \frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}} \right)\\
\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \operatorname{d}x &= \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}}}{\left( 1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Now comes the hard part: Solving the ODE for y(x).

*(From here only my failed attempts follow...)*

---

#### My first attempt at solving the ODE

Since I can't think of a specific solution, I would try a bit of reshaping first.
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \operatorname{d}x &= \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}}}{\left( 1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \operatorname{d}x &= \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}}}{\left( 1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2} \right)^{3 \cdot \frac{1}{2}}}\\
\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \operatorname{d}x &= \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}}}{\left( \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \right)^{3}} \quad\mid\quad u\left( x \right) := \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}}\\
\int_{0}^{x} u\left( x \right) \operatorname{d}x &= \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}}}{u\left( x \right)^{3}} \quad\mid\quad \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \tag{1.}\\
\int_{0}^{x} u\left( x \right) \operatorname{d}x \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} &= \frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}}\\
\\
u\left( x \right) &= \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \quad\mid\quad \left(  \right)^{2}\\
u\left( x \right)^{2} &= 1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2} \quad\mid\quad -1\\
u\left( x \right)^{2} - 1 &= \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2} \quad\mid\quad \sqrt{}\\
\sqrt{u\left( x \right)^{2} - 1} &= \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \quad\mid\quad \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\\
\frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}u\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}}{2 \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1}} &= \frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}} \tag{2.}\\
\\
\int_{0}^{x} u\left( x \right) \operatorname{d}x \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} &= \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}u\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}}{2 \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

And I'm stuck aigan.

#### My second attempt at solving the ODE

Next, I would try to transform the higher-order nonlinear ODE into a third-order nonlinear ODE, because maybe that will help. Since the substitution simplified the equation in my opinion, I use it again.
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \operatorname{d}x &= \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}}}{\left( 1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \quad\mid\quad \text{useing } \left( 1. \right) \text{ and } \left( 2. \right)\\
\int_{0}^{x} u\left( x \right) \operatorname{d}x &= \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}u\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}}{2 \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1}} \quad\mid\quad \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\\
\\
u\left( x \right) &= \dots
\end{align*}
$$

Time to give up... [Since it looks harder now.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5Bd%2Cdx%5D%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bu%27%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%20Power%5Bu%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D%20Sqrt%5Bu%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29-1%5D%5D%5C%2841%29)

---

#### My numerical attempt

We know from calculus $\frac{\operatorname{d}f\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} = \frac{f\left( x + h \right) - f\left( x \right)}{h} + \mathcal{O}\left( h \right)$ or $\frac{\operatorname{d}f\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \approx \frac{f\left( x + h \right) - f\left( x \right)}{h}, \text{for small } \left| h \right|$ [(Euler method)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations#Euler_method) aka:

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \operatorname{d}x &= \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}}}{\left( 1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \quad\mid\quad \text{useing } \left( 1. \right) \text{ and } \left( 2. \right)\\
\int_{0}^{x} u\left( x \right) \operatorname{d}x &= \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}u\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}}{2 \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1}}\\
\int_{0}^{x} u\left( x \right) \operatorname{d}x &\approx \frac{\frac{u\left( x + h \right) - u\left( x \right)}{h}}{2 \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1}}\\
\int_{0}^{x} u\left( x \right) \operatorname{d}x &\approx \frac{u\left( x + h \right) - u\left( x \right)}{2 \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot h} \quad\mid\quad \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\\
u\left( x \right) &\approx \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x} \frac{u\left( x + h \right) - u\left( x \right)}{2 \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot h}\\
u\left( x \right) &\approx \frac{\frac{u\left( x + 2 \cdot h \right) - u\left( x + h \right)}{2 \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x + h \right) - 1} \cdot h} - \frac{u\left( x + h \right) - u\left( x \right)}{2 \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot h}}{h}\\
u\left( x \right) &\approx \frac{u\left( x + 2 \cdot h \right) - u\left( x + h \right)}{2 \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x + h \right) - 1} \cdot h^{2}} - \frac{u\left( x + h \right) - u\left( x \right)}{2 \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot h^{2}}\\
u\left( x \right) &\approx \frac{u\left( x + 2 \cdot h \right) \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} - u\left( x + h \right) \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3}}{2 \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x + h \right) - 1} \cdot h^{2}} - \frac{u\left( x + h \right) \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} - u\left( x \right) \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3}}{2 \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot h^{2}}\\
u\left( x \right) &\approx \frac{u\left( x + 2 \cdot h \right) \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} - u\left( x + h \right) \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} - \left( u\left( x + h \right) \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} - u\left( x \right) \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} \right)}{2 \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot h^{2}} \quad\mid\quad \cdot \left( 2 \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot h^{2} \right)\\
u\left( x \right) \cdot 2 \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot h^{2} &\approx u\left( x + 2 \cdot h \right) \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} - u\left( x + h \right) \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} - \left( u\left( x + h \right) \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} - u\left( x \right) \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} \right)\\
u\left( x \right)^{4} \cdot 2 \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3} \cdot \sqrt{u\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot h^{2} &\approx u\left( x + 2 \cdot h \right) \cdot u\left( x \right)^{6} - u\left( x + h \right) \cdot u\left( x \right)^{3} - u\left( x + h \right)^{4} + u\left( x \right) \cdot u\left( x + h \right)^{3}\\
\end{align*}
$$
Time to give up, since this dosn't look solvable for me...

---

I am grateful for every help, correction and suggestion.

Comment: Taking $\frac d{dx}$ on both sides gives [no exact form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=√%281%2By’%28x%29%5E2%29%3Dddx+y’’%28x%29%2F%28y’%28x%29%5E2%2B1%29%5E%283%2F2%29)

Comment: lookup [Euler spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral), you $y(x)$ should be expressable in terms of [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) and their inverse. I think it is $\sqrt{2}S(C^{-1}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}))$.

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162558/curve-where-torsion-and-curvature-equal-arc-length/3162727#3162727

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that the defining condition determines an [Euler spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral).

Per OP's comment, here's how to construct an explicit parameterization of an (essentially general) curve $\gamma$ satisfying the condition. In the end we'll exploit the construction to describe a function $y(x)$ satisfying the condition.

The Frenet equations in $2$ dimensions, satisfied by the curvature $\kappa(s)$, tangent vector ${\bf T}(s)$, and normal vector ${\bf N}(s)$, are
$$\pmatrix{{\bf T}' & {\bf N}'} = \pmatrix{{\bf T} & {\bf N}} \pmatrix{\cdot&-\kappa\\\kappa&\cdot} .$$ As usual, $s$ is the arc length parameter.
In our case, $\kappa(s) = s$, so our differential equation becomes
$$\pmatrix{{\bf T}' & {\bf N}'} = \pmatrix{{\bf T} & {\bf N}} s \pmatrix{\cdot&-1\\1&\cdot},$$
and rearranging gives
$$\pmatrix{{\bf T} & {\bf N}}^{-1}\pmatrix{{\bf T}' & {\bf N}'} = s \pmatrix{\cdot&-1\\1&\cdot} ,$$
so
\begin{align*}
\pmatrix{{\bf T} & {\bf N}}
&= \pmatrix{{\bf T}(0) & {\bf N}(0)} \exp \int_0^s \left[u\pmatrix{\cdot&-1\\1&\cdot}\right] du\\
&= \pmatrix{{\bf T}(0) & {\bf N}(0)} \exp \left[\pmatrix{\cdot&-1\\1&\cdot} \int_0^s u \,du\right] \\
&= \pmatrix{{\bf T}(0) & {\bf N}(0)} \exp \left[\frac{1}{2} s^2 \pmatrix{\cdot&-1\\1&\cdot}\right] \\
&=\pmatrix{{\bf T}(0) & {\bf N}(0)} \pmatrix{\cos \frac{s^2}{2} & \ast \\ \sin \frac{s^2}{2} & \ast}.
\end{align*}
If we denote ${\bf T}(0) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, then
$${\bf T} = \pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta} \pmatrix{\cos \frac{s^2}{2} \\ \sin \frac{s^2}{2}}.$$ Integrating and setting $\gamma(0) = 0$ gives
$$\gamma(s) = \int_0^s {\bf T}'(u) \,du = \pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta} \pmatrix{\int_0^s \cos \frac{u^2}{2} \,du \\  \int_0^s \sin \frac{u^2}{2} \,du} .$$ So, up to rotation, there is a unique curve satisfying $\gamma(0) = 0$. Taking $\theta = 0$ to choose a representative we find that
$$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{\gamma(s) = \pmatrix{\int_0^s \cos \frac{u^2}{2} \,du \\ \int_0^s \sin \frac{u^2}{2} \,du} = \pmatrix{\sqrt{2} C\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt 2}\right) \\ \sqrt{2} S\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt 2}\right)}}},$$ where $C$ and $S$ are the [Fresnel integral functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

*The solution curve $\gamma$, $s \in [-32, 32]$.*
[image]

The Fresnel cosine function $C$ is injective in a neighborhood of $x = 0$, so it admits a local inverse, $C^{-1}$, in which case a solution $y(x)$ to the original o.d.e. is $$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{y(x) = \sqrt{2} S\left(C^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}} ,$$ in agreement with achille hui's comment.

*The function $y(x)$ with maximum domain.*
[image]

We can verify directly that the truncation of the power series of $y$ agrees with that in my other answer:
$$y(x) = \frac16 x^3 + \frac1{105} x^7 + \frac{293}{237600} x^{11} + \cdots .$$

Comment: Shouldn't $\gamma(s) = \pmatrix{\int_0^s \cos \frac{u^2}{2} \,du \\ \int_0^s \sin \frac{u^2}{2} \,du} = \pmatrix{\sqrt{2} C\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt 2}\right) \\ \sqrt{2} S\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt 2}\right)}$ be [$\gamma(s) = \pmatrix{\int_0^s \cos \frac{u^2}{2} \,du \\ \int_0^s \sin \frac{u^2}{2} \,du} = \pmatrix{\sqrt{\pi} C\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right) \\ \sqrt{\pi} S\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7BIntegrate%5Bcos%28u%5E2%2F2%29%2C%7Bu%2C0%2Cs%7D%5D%2C+Integrate%5Bsin%28u%5E2%2F2%29%2C%7Bu%2C0%2Cs%7D%5D%7D)?
Or am I wrong?

Comment: @KevinDietrich there are more than one conventions for Fresnel integrals. What you are referred to is called normalized Fresnel integral in wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Your DE is simply $w'w=y''$ where $w(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt {1+y'^2(t) }dt$
$$\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \operatorname{d}x = \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}}}{\left( 1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\$$
$$2\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \operatorname{d}x {\left( 1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=2y''$$
$$\left (\left (\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} \right)^{2}} \operatorname{d}x \right)^{2}\right)'=2y''$$
I think that you can reduce the order by direct integration.
$$\int_0^x\sqrt {1+p^2(t)}dt=\pm \sqrt {2p+C_1}$$
$$\sqrt {1+p^2}=\pm \dfrac {p'}{\sqrt {2p+C_1}}$$
Where $p=y'=\dfrac {dy}{dx}$ and $p'=\dfrac {dp}{dx}$. The last DE is separable maybe not easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a closed-form solution for an explicit function $y(x)$, but we can make some progress.

Differentiating both sides of the equation and rearranging gives the $3$rd order o.d.e.
$$(1 + (y')^2)^3 = y'''(x) \left[(y')^2 + 1\right] - 3 (y'')^2 y' ,$$ and writing $u := y'$ reduces it to a $2$nd order equation,
$$(1 + u^2)^3 = u'' (1 + u^2) - 3 (u')^2 u .$$
Swapping the independent and dependent variables, i.e., regarding $x$ as a function of $u$, yields the equation
$$x''(u) = -(1 + u^2)^2 x'(u)^3 - \frac{3 u x'(u)}{1 + u^2}.$$ We may now reduce to a $1$st order equation in $z := x'$:
$$z' = -(1 + u^2)^2 z^3 - \frac{3 u z}{1 + u^2} .$$
Substituting $z(u) = \frac{1}{(1 + u^2)^{3 / 2} \sqrt{w(u)}}$ transforms the equation to
$$w'(u) = \frac{2}{u^2 + 1},$$
or
$$w(u) = 2 \arctan u + C.$$
Backsubstituting yields the generic solutions
$$z(u) = \pm \frac{1}{(u^2 + 1)^{3 / 2} (\sqrt{2 \arctan u + C})}$$
and thus
$$x(u) = \pm \int_a^u \frac{dt}{(t^2 + 1)^{3 / 2} (\sqrt{2 \arctan t + C})} .$$ The integral on the right-hand side likely has no closed form, but the inverse of this $x(u)$ is $u(x) = y'(x)$, and integrating again gives $y(x)$.

Incidentally, we can compute the truncation of a series solution: Setting $y(0) = 0$, $y'(0) = a$, $y''(0) = b$ gives
$$y(x) = a x + \frac{1}{2} b x^2 + \frac{1}{6} \left[(1 + a^2)^2 + \frac{3 a b^2}{1 + a^2}\right] x^3 + \cdots .$$
Taking $a = b = 0$ yields the solution with the highest order of tangency to the $x$-axis:
$$y(x) = \frac16 x^3 + \frac1{105} x^7 + \frac{293}{237600} x^{11} + \cdots .$$